# What's the official name for a space that warps like this?

Tags: general-topology, loop-spaces, riemann-sphere

For years, games have had this idea of a space that warps.  Attempting to move out of the playing field on the left side would send you to the right side, like in Pac-Man.  But is there an official name for this kind of space?

When I thought of this kind of space, I thought about single point convergence with complex numbers, as you can see [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere)  What happens when you go left (negative) in the Real direction is that you will reach a point of infinity and then come back around from the Positive Reals.

I'm not sure if this is simply a Riemann Sphere or more.

Comment: Pacman plays on the surface of a cylinder and snake on the surface of a torus.

Comment: Pac-man might be on a torus. We don't have enough evidence to rule it out. :)

Comment: @MJD Yes, I agree. One could simply say it is a torus and place walls so that it seems cylindrical to the player.